# iOS: CGPath Line Drawing with dynamic width

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-graphics

I want to draw a line with dynamic width as shown in attached picture. What should be the best approach for this. ?

[image]

**Updated:**

My task is to draw line on finger move. And the line width is changes as speed of swipe is change. both (Line width and finger swipe speed) are directly proportional  .

Comment: Don't know it this will help you. Quite a late reply : http://merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for variable thickness curves in iOS (or Mac OS for that matter.) The  cocos2d project looks like a good approach.

There is also no support for soft-edged curves who's edges are feathered to transparent. I've thought about implementing a similar approach to the one outlined in the Cocos link using OpenGL. This would be a good application for a vertex shader, since it would take advantage of the parallel vertex processing and vector math available in shaders.

Answer (score 0):

As the image you posted doesn't has any consistent height-width proportion to calculate and change, i doubt this cannot be achieved. 
In other solution you can draw a line of fixed pixel say 2 pixel and based on drawn length inflate the width if line till center and then again start deflate from center point to end point.

You need to see the difference between x coordinates otherwise if a sine wave is drawn with high nodes the line width will overlap each other.

Edited : [This link](http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/) might be of your interest then.You can modify it according to your need, its in cocos2d.

Comment: you can download this project"https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/smooth-drawing". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article [Smooth Freehand Drawing](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/). It might be helpfull.
You can manipulate with control points of

```
[path addCurveToPoint:pts[3] controlPoint1:pts[1] controlPoint2:pts[2]];
```

and fill the area between two bezierPaths. I am not sure if it will work, but you can try if you dont find anything else.